# Python 3 Parse file to find blocks of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, dictionary, classification

Ok, so if I had the following code:

```
a = 1
b = 2
count_one = 0
count_two = 0
ex_array = [a,b]

for i in ex_array:
    print(i)
    if i == 2:
        print("Two")
    elif i == 1:
         print("One")
```

my goal is to classify the code into code blocks(and sub-blocks).

By this I mean:

One block is the entire code, let's call this "level one".
Within the "level one" block there is also:

```
for i in ex_array:
    print(i)
    if i == 2:
        print("Two")
    elif i == 1:
         print("One")
```

Let's call this the "level two" block.
Within the level two block there is also:

```
if i == 2:
    print("Two")
```

and

```
if i == 1:
    print("One")
```

This level is "level three":

So there is 1 Code block in "level one"(the complete code), 1 Code block in "level two"(the `for` loop containing the `if` and `elif` statements) and 2 code blocks in level three(the `if` and `elif` statements).

Once I have classified the code blocks and the levels I would like to add them to a dictionary like so:

```
code_block_dictionary = {0:(0,"Entire code"), 1:(1,"The for loop block"), 2:(2,"The if statement"), 3:(2,"The `elif` statement")}
```

Where the first number is an index/key, the second is the level and the third is the code at that level.

In the end, I would like to be able to do something like:

> Enter level to select block from:

I type '3'

> There are 2 blocks of code at this level
>
> Enter block number to print:

I type '1' and the resulting string printed to the terminal is:

```
if i == 2:
    print("Two")
```

I hope all of this made sense.
If any more information is needed please ask and I will do my best.
Thanks

Comment: the question is clear. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: python offers some introspection on source files, e.g. `import inspect, mymodule` and then `inspect.getSource(mymodule)` but you'll only get the source code and you'll need to parse it for your self. [here] is the documentation for source inspection

Comment: look at the `tokenize` module. count `INDENT` tokens.

Comment: Will also check out tokenize, Thanks

Comment: You might also have fun exploring `ast.NodeVisitor`. FWIW, `elif condition:` is syntactic sugar for `else: if condition:` so a flat `if... elif... elif` sequence gets transformed into a nested structure in the AST.

Comment: @PM2Ring Wow! I had never heard of ast. It is awesome! Thanks heaps :)